# error while running socket.io program

Tags: node.js, cygwin, socket.io

I downloaded this program

https://github.com/DanBUK/bejesus-socket-io-demo

but when i do

```
node socket-demo.js
```

It gives me this error

```
 node socket-demo.js

node.js:50
    throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
    ^
WideCharToMultiByte: The data area passed to a system call is too small.
TypeError: Bad argument
    at Object.stat (fs.js:328:11)
    at Server.<anonymous> (net.js:1093:19)
    at Server.listen (/usr/local/lib/node/.npm/express/1.0.7/package/lib/express
/server.js:101:35)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/Administrator/socket-io-demo/socket-demo.js:15:
5)
    at Module._compile (node.js:329:23)
    at Object..js (node.js:337:12)
    at Module.load (node.js:260:25)
    at Array.<anonymous> (node.js:351:24)
    at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:42:22)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The application expects the environment variables `app_port` and `app_host`. Try

```
$ export app_port=8000
$ export app_host=localhost
$ node socket-demo.js
```